# Reducing number of XY points within distance of one another using Integrate tool in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, xy

I have XY data (lat/lon) that I'm importing into ArcMap.  I need to reduce the data to eliminate points that are within a certain distance of one another.  For example, if two points are less than 1km apart, I want to only retain one.

I thought this could be done with Integrate, which did allow my to successfully collapse all points within 1km to single points on the map, but all the original points are still in the underlying attribute table.  Is there a way to create a new attribute table or shapefile with just these "collapsed" points that I see on the map?  If there is a better tool for this, I'd be happy to know but I haven't been able to find anything else nor any tips on how to extract these new points after using the Integrate tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the [Dissolve tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) but you have to first [calculate two fields that represent the X and Y](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) of every points. Points with identical coordinates (i.e., those that have been moved into the same place after running the Integrate tool) will be dissolved into single points. You can choose how you want to handle the attributes of every point in the group of points that share the same spot.

Alternatively, there is a tool [Collect Events](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/collect-events.htm) that will create a single point from those points that share the same spot and will add a new attribute to the output feature class telling you how many points this "aggregated" point represents.